# Laravel: Access original view data when the 404 page is shown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller rendering **my_view.blade.php**. The view has access to specific variables:

```
return view()->make('my_view', array('var1' => 'foo', 'var2' => 'bar'));
```

Now, let's say a page using the **my_view.blade.php** throws a 404 error. In this case, Laravel will "swap" **my_view** for the the custom **404.blade.php**.

When this happens, the **404** view has no knowledge of the originally passed data, obviously.

Is there any way I can persist the original data passed to **my_view**, so they can be accessed within **404.blade.php**? Note that this data could be dynamic, different for every view.

Of course, the solution would handle any page throwing 404.

Comment: If you get a 404 error then the original view is not rendered. There's no original view data applicable in that case. There's no generic solution for this I don't think.

Comment: Crap, of course, you're right. I fire `abort(404)`, so the data is not passed to any view at all. Also, there's currently no way to pass data to the method.

Comment: If you manually fire `abort` then you can still do `view()->share(...)` before this as suggested by @ian (unless you're firing this in middleware), the problem generally is when you have a model bound to a route which auto-fires 404 when it does not exist. Then you're pretty much out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `view()->share($key, $val)` this will share it amongst all views in that request.

You can view the docs on sharing data with views on the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views) docs

Comment: This is fine if I *know* what I need to share, if there's some pre-defined key-pair set. In my case, I would like to share the data of the original view with the (dynamically rendered) 404 view. I don't see how to use `share` for this.

Comment: @lesssugar you can pass a keyval array into the share method. You must know what you want to pass otherwise how will the view know..? You are passing var1 and var2 at the moment, so put that in an array and use the above solution.

Comment: Well, that's the point of my post: I want the rendered 404 view to automatically have access to the same data the original view used, regardless of what it was. This means I, indeed, don't know the data beforehand.

Comment: Ahh I see, then I'm not sure, I don't think it would be possible in my 404 I have a few optional fields that I can pass through whenever I expect a 404, but it isn't dynamic.